# Implementar "add to favorites" en Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

soy nuevo en Rails y necesito vuestra ayuda para implementar una funcionalidad en mi web app. Se trata de una web app de recetas y la funcionalidad en cuestión es "Añadir receta a Favoritos". Al "User" lo llamo "Chef". Quiero que un chef pueda guardarse recetas de otros chefs.

**En los modelos tengo las siguientes asociaciones:**

chef.rb:

```
has_many :favorites
has_many :recipes, through: :favorites
```

recipe.rb:

```
has_many :favorites
has_many :chefs, through: :favorites
```

favorite.rb:

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chef
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

**En el archivo de migración he creado una tabla de favorito:**

```
t.belongs_to :chef
t.belongs_to :recipe
t.timestamps
```

**En routes.rb:**

```
get 'my_favorites', to: 'chefs#my_favorites'
resources :favorites
post 'add_recipe', to: 'recipes#add_recipe'
```

**En RecipesController he definido:**

```
def my_favorites
 @favorites = current_chef.recipes
end

def add_recipe
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id]) 
  current_chef.favorites.build(recipe_id: @recipe.id)

  if @recipe.save
     redirect_to my_favorites_path, notice: "Favorite recipe was 
                                           successfully added"
  else
     redirect_to my_favorites_path, flash[:error] = "There was an error 
                                     with adding recipe as favorite"
  end
end
```

**En views:**

H creado un botón "add as my favorite" link_to en el archivo views/recipes/show.html.erb. Pero **cuando hago click en él desde el navegador me da este error: 'Couldn't find Recipe without an ID'**

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <% if current_chef.not_favorites_with?(@recipe) %>
    <%= link_to "Add as my favorite", add_recipe_path(chef: 
                                  current_chef, recipe: @chef), 
                                  class: "btn btn-xs btn-success", 
                                  method: :post %>
  <% else %>
    <span class="label label-primary">
      It's already your favorite recipe
    </span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Esto es lo que ocurre en el servidor:**

```
Processing by RecipesController#add_recipe as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Pz5C/yK0mP5QtONHJs83fhxcrQ6Alvbp2qpPrVOiKdBKyIUyspww/7L8S66lcOmFGWZr8Lq1ka1rt2D4FbY8NQ==", "chef"=>"9"}
Chef Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "chefs".* FROM "chefs" WHERE "chefs"."id" = ? ORDER BY "chefs"."created_at" DESC LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)  

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Recipe without an ID):
```

**No se porqué no puede encontrar el "recipe's ID". Por favor, ayuda.**

https://github.com/0rdinaryman/myrecipes

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta al español por favor. Este sitio está completamente en español ¬_¬

Comment: Hi.. the official language of the site is spanish. If spanish is your first language, please translate it.

Comment: Entendido! Lo acabo de traducir. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

> link_to "Add as my favorite", add_recipe_path(chef: 
>                                     current_chef, recipe: @chef), 
>                                     class: "btn btn-xs btn-success", 
>                                     method: :post

La acción recipes#add_recipe está esperando un parametro con key :id (el id de recipe) y tu no se lo estás enviando. Envías una key :recipe con el chef en lugar de la receta. Entonces en el controlador, al momento de hacer Recipe.find(params[:id]), params[:id] devuelve nil y se lanza la excepción.

La solución está en enviar siempre primero el objeto del controlador (en este caso recipe) y luego los parámetros adicionales:

Prueba modificando el link_to a

```
link_to "Add as my favorite", add_recipe_path(@recipe, chef: current_chef), class: "btn btn-xs btn-success", method: :post
```

Comment: gracias cmramseyer, pero no ha habido suerte. Me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Prueba poniendo un debugger al comienzo de add_recipe en el controlador y ejecuta el método params para ver qué es lo que está llegando. Deberías modificar los argumentos de add_recipe_path en el link_to hasta que puedas ver { id: 123 } por ejemplo